# Difference b/w Object.defineProperty vs directly assigning a property to object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this piece of code

```
let person=new Object({
                       fname: 'Uday',
                       sname: 'Kiran',
                       getFName: function(){
                       return this.fname;
                      }
                     });

Object.defineProperty(person,'getSName',
                      {
                          value: function(){return this.sname;},
                          writable: false,
                          enumerable: true,
                          configurable: true
                      });

let personInherited=Object.create(person);
```

This is possible, I'm able to override getSName property with the help of `Object.defineProperty` eventhough it is defined as `writable: false` in `person`.

```
Object.defineProperty(personInherited,'getSName',
                      {
                         value: function(){
                                            return this.sname.toUpperCase();
                      },
                      writable: true,
                      enumerable: true,
                      configurable: true
                      });
```

But I'm not able override the getSName property like below.

```
personInherited.getSName=function(){
                                      return this.sname;
                                   }
```

Can someone please explain what is the difference between creating a property by using `Object.defineProperty` and directly assigning property using `personInherited.getSName`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty there is all information you need to understand the diffrence

Comment: @mtizziani That doesn't explain how assignment and `defineProperty` differ for inherited properties that have `writable: false` (and/or `configurable: false`?), does it? That's what this question is asking about.

Comment: [The documentation for `Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) is very clear;  `writable: false` means the Property can't be re-assigned.  Using `.defineProperty` on a Property that already exists, you are **modifying** the Property, rather than **assigning** it.  The only way to prevent the usage of `.defineProperty` is to set the Property to `configurable : false`;  However, this still allows the `writable` attribute to be changed.

Comment: @Claies Note that in the OP's example, setting `configurable: false` on the inherited property does not prevent setting a new instance property with `defineProperty`. I really don't think this is a situation handled well by MDN's documentation, because it fails to explain the difference in behavior for inherited properties versus own properties. In this case, `personInherited` doesn't have its own `getSName` property (it is inherited) and the only way to give it its own `getSName` property is by `defineProperty` since `writable: false` is specified to prevent the creation of an own-property.